# Create histogram with rotated string labels in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab table with the following specification: The first column is the property name and the second is the times it occurs. [Here](http://pastebin.com/z4tPRA63) is the complete csv-file with the data. This is an excerpt:

```
RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,240
RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,184
RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,464
...
```

Now I want to plot the histogram as well as show the frequency property names below. So it maybe looks like this (sorry for the crude drawing):

[image: example]

**Please don't take the bars figuratively, they are just a sample to show how I want the text labels below, the grouping of the bars is not significant.**

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have an actual `table` or is it a file? Can you provide the code needed to produce the table? Also, what are the two groups of bars representing?

Comment: @Suever I have a file, I generated the table by importing into matlab. Please don't take the bars figuratively, they are just a sample to show how I want the text labels below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you can read-in your data with `table`, which is very convenient to use. Then, plot the bars with `bar` using the data of the second column of the table, addressed with `T{:,2}`. The additional space on the right side of the plot can be cropped by manually setting the `XLim`-property.

After that, we construct the text of the labels. Therefore you want to concatenate the first column of the table with the string-representation of the number in the second column of the table. `strcat` can do the concatenation of the cell array `T{:,1}` and the cell array returned by `arrayfun` and puts the `,` between them as specified.

Now we need to set the `XTick...`-properties to get the desired result: `XTick` specifies the position of the ticks along the x-axis. `XTickLabel` defines the text of the labels at the before defined positions. With `XTickLabelRotation` we can rotate the label by a given amount in degrees. Finally, `TickLabelInterpreter` is set to `none` to prevent text after underscores to be subscripted.

*Here is the code for that:*

```
% read data into table
T = readtable('path_0.csv');

% draw bars
figure;
bar(1:size(T,1),T{:,2});
set(gca,'XLim',[0,size(T,1)+1]);
grid on;

% change labels
xLabels = strcat(T{:,1},',',arrayfun(@num2str,T{:,2},'UniformOutput',false));
set(gca,'XLim',[0,size(T,1)+1],...
        'XTick',1:length(xLabels),...
        'XTickLabel',xLabels,...
        'XTickLabelRotation',45,...
        'TickLabelInterpreter','none');
```

*Here is the produced figure:*
[image: result]